# Getting data from Database and storing into Dictionary

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, dictionary

I am trying to get the data from a MySQL table and storing it into a dictionary. I know I can do that with a loop but DB table contains more than a million tuples and will slow the progress. Is there any way to do that without having to loop all the entries?

DB table has two columns, 1st(key) float type and 2nd(value) varchar.

My Current approach:

```
public static Dictionary<Single, string> GetData()
{
   Dictionary<Single, string> dic= new Dictionary<Single, string>();
   string query = "select * from table;";
   if (OpenConnection() == true)
   {
        try
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
            MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.Read())
            {

               //Something to store DB columns into dictionary without having to loop.  

            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
   }
   return dic;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a rule as _without having to loop_ at all? What is _wrong_ using a loop?

Comment: The basic idea is to perform long processes on a thread different from the main to not hangs the GUI. You can show a progress bar or another kind of waiting message.

Comment: Well actually it is just a smaller part of bigger problem and I can't spend too much time on it. looping will make my tool's overall performance very slow.

Comment: First of all, is your table only 2 columns? Select only what you need and the part of data you need, not the whole million

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next is what you want:

```
try
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
        MySqlDataAdapter msda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        msda.Fill(ds);
        your_control.DataSource = ds;
        your_control.DataBind();
        //your control means some repeater, or gridview, or anything else, which may show all your elements together.
    }
```

But you also should consider that if you have millions of records, it would be better to make them selected partially. For example, 100 records per page, using row_number or similar methods

Comment: can I extract data from DataSet into a dictionary?

Comment: @AbdulRehman You have to use loop anyway. I would like offer foreach loop